# Get repetition count of array of objects with average value

Tags: javascript

I Have a dataset that looks like this:

```
var arr = [
  { userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8", profitLoss: 401.4 },
  { userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8", profitLoss: -28.36 },
  { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: -26.14 },
  { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: 46.14},
  { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: 86.14}
];
```

Now I want the repetition count of userid with average value of profitLoss.

```
Expected result will be like this:
var arr = [
  { userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8", profitLoss: 186.52, count: 2 },
  { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: 106.14, count: 3}
];
```

I know to get the repetition count of array but not on object;
for repetition count of array the logic will be like this:

```
var map = arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
  prev[cur] = (prev[cur] || 0) + 1;
  return prev;
}, {});
```

But I am confused on array of objects.

Comment: is your data sorted? how do you get `186.52` for the first part?

Comment: I manually calculate. Just try to explain my desired result. I want the average of profit loss of same userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create dictionary with userid as key and object with sum and count. Then it's enough to map entries to your result.

```js
var arr = [
  { userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8", profitLoss: 401.4 },
  { userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8", profitLoss: -28.36 },
  { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: -26.14 },
  { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: 46.14},
  { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: 86.14}
];

var userDict = arr.reduce((acc, el)=>{
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(el.userid)){
    acc[el.userid] = {sum: 0, count: 0}
  }
  acc[el.userid].sum += el.profitLoss;
  acc[el.userid].count++;
  return acc;
}, {});

var result = Object.entries(userDict).map(([k,v])=>({userid: k, average: v.sum/v.count, count:v.count}));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the best approach. Really appreciated for this

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and sum the values an count. Later get the average.

```js
var array = [{ userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8", profitLoss: 401.4 }, { userid: "5bacc98431481e0520856df8", profitLoss: -28.36 }, { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: -26.14 }, { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: 46.14 }, { userid: "5bacc8c6563a882a1ca7756a", profitLoss: 86.14 }],
    result = Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, { userid, profitLoss }) => {
            var temp = m.get(userid) || { sum: 0, count: 0 };
            temp.sum += profitLoss;
            temp.count++;
            return m.set(userid, temp);
        }, new Map),
        ([userid, { sum, count }]) => ({ userid, average: sum / count, count })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: really appreciated for your effort.